# Why isn't the color function for ggplot2 (R) working?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to set colors in my ggplot to change based on a variable. This should be relatively simple and I've done it before, but I'm getting an odd error message. Thoughts on how to fix this? Thanks!

This is the code Im using:

```
ggplot(partymeans, aes(x=Year, y=Average.LCV.Score)) + geom_point(color =partymeans$Party) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("D" = "royalblue1",
                               "I" = "plum4",
                               "R" = "firebrick"))
```

And this is the error message I am getting:
Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : invalid color name 'D'.

Adding a sample of the data I used for the plot where the color is not working:

```
head(partymeans)
Year Party Average.LCV.Score
1 2000     D          81.06522
2 2001     D          80.98000
3 2002     D          66.56000
4 2003     D          69.45833
5 2004     D          83.31250
6 2005     D          81.47727
```

The "Party" changes to R and I in later parts of the dataset.

** When I tried to change the shape by the same variable, it worked, so it seems to be an issue with the color. Obviously, the shape differentiation is not as visually pleasing as the colors.

I tried something similar earlier in the code using:

```
box2019.1 <- qplot(x= Party, y=LCV.Score, fill = Party, data = Senate.2019, geom = "boxplot")
box2019.1 + labs(title = "Boxplot of 2019 Senators' LCV Scores by Party", y= "2019 LCV Score") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("D" = "royalblue1",
                               "I" = "plum4",
                               "R" = "firebrick"), 
                    labels = c("Democratic", "Independent", "Republican")) + theme_bw() +
                    theme(legend.position = "top")
```

and that worked to create the attached boxplot is so I'm not sure what the issue is :( Any help would be appreciated!

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to put `color = Party` inside the `aes()` tag within the `geom_point()` function:

```r
ggplot(partymeans, aes(x=Year, y=Average.LCV.Score)) +
    geom_point(aes(color =Party)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("D" = "royalblue1",
                               "I" = "plum4",
                               "R" = "firebrick"))
```

Before it was reading the "D", "I" and "R" values as colour names. `aes()` is what you want to pass these values to the `scale_color_manual` (do note to change from `_fill_` to `_color_`).

Here's an example using the `iris` dataset to show how it works (with the same colours):

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Species)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("setosa" = "royalblue1",
                                 "versicolor" = "plum4",
                                 "virginica" = "firebrick"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: no problem! the `qplot` function you used in the other example is behind the scenes putting the `fill = Party` part in an `aes()` call, which is why it looks different.